# How to disable hyperlinks in selected MailItem instances?

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm looking for a way to disable all hyperlinks in certain emails, but so far the only solution I've found was to set `MailItem`'s body property with an version of the original email body that includes no links, which causes some problems.  Does anyone know if there is an effective way to disable the links in an email body?

Comment: What problems do you get with the existing solution?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev among the problems, Outlook saves the `MailItem` object silently (overwrites the original email) and when the `Inspector` is closed without explicitly saving the `MailItem`object a dialog box is prompted.

Comment: You can save it too for preventing dialogs shown to a user. You can keep old URL information in the HTML content or add a user property for that, for example. When the item is closed you may recover the original data.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev you're right, but saving `MailItem`objects causes some serious usability and even ethical problems. If we save `MailItem` objects then we're changing the original message, which the user may interpret as a malicious act, and if for some reason Outlook is closed in an ungraceful manner (power outage, crash, etc) then the original `MailItem` will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for handling hyperlinks clicks. As a possible workaround you may consider implementing the following functionality:

1. When the item is selected or opened in Outlook you may replace the original URL with your own where you can pass the original URL as an encoded parameter if needed. So, if it is allowed to open the URL you can redirect the request further.
2. Another possible solution is to register a custom URL handler. So, basically, your registered application will be launched instead of a web browser. See [Installing and Registering Protocol Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.